# error: no type named 'vector' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Why this is happening?

> error: no type named 'vector' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'hecto'?
>   void askForVector(std::vector * vector);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void askForVector(std::vector * vector);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector;
    int size;
    askForVector(&vector);
    std::cout << "\nsize: " << vector.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << vector.at(0);
}


void askForVector(std::vector * vector)
{
    int size;
    std::cout << "please insert the size of vector to order: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    vector->resize(size);

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        std::cout <<  "please insert a value for the " << i+1 << " position: " ;
        std::cin >> vector[i];
    }

    for(int j: *vector)
        std::cout << ":"<<j;
    std::cout  << ":\n";
}
```

Comment: `vector` is a class template, not a class.

Comment: Also, passing a raw pointer when you don't need to re-assign it it's not the best idea - I'd recommend you to pass the `vector` by reference: in function header use `&` insted of `*`, and use the argument like a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Lidia: if one answer solved your problems, consider marking it as accepted as soon as possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`vector` is a template, not a type. Either specify a particular specialisation:

```
void askForVector(std::vector<int> * vector);
```

or make the function generic

```
template <typename T>
void askForVector(std::vector<T> * vector);
```

You might be better off using a reference rather than a pointer:

```
void askForVector(std::vector<int> & vector);
```

or returning the vector by value:

```
std::vector<int> askForVector() {
    std::vector<int> vector;
    // your code here
    return vector;
}
```

to avoid errors like

```
std::cin >> vector[i]; // should be (*vector)[i]
```

Comment: when I use the template as you say, I get an awkward error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "askForVector(std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >*)", referenced from:
      _main in insertionsort-GrnjUF.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: @LidiaFreitas: It sounds like you defined the template in one source file and tried to use it in another. Templates usually have to be defined in a header, since the definition is needed in every source file that needs to instantiate it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues:

1. vector is a template, not a type, you need the template argument list e.g. `vector<int>` in the function signature
2. Since you're passing a pointer to a vector you need to dereference it *before* using the subscript operator

   ```
   std::cin >> vector[i]; // wrong
   std::cin >> (*vector)[i]; // correct
   ```

The following could work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void askForVector(std::vector<int> * vector);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector;
    int size;
    askForVector(&vector);
    std::cout << "\nsize: " << vector.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << vector.at(0);

}


void askForVector(std::vector<int> * vector)
{
    int size;
    std::cout << "please insert the size of vector to order: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    vector->resize(size);

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        std::cout << "please insert a value for the " << i + 1 << " position: ";
        std::cin >> (*vector)[i];
    }

    for (int j : *vector)
        std::cout << ":" << j;
    std::cout << ":\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/BfKXvc)</kbd>

Comment: That weird cast is unnecessary, and somewhat dangerous. `(*vector)[i]` is all that's needed to access a vector element.

Comment: That is true, although I somewhat prefer to be overly verbose to explain things effectively. Editing..